Constrained Least Squares with Bounds and Optimality Conditions
For the below least squares problem with linear constraints
$$
\min_x ||Ax-b||^2 
$$
$$
s.t.\;\;Cx=d
$$
we arrive at the following optimality conditions using Lagrange multipliers
$$
\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
2A^TA & C^T \\
C & 0 \end{array} \right]
\left[\begin{array}{c} 
x\\
z\end{array} \right]=
\left[\begin{array}{c} 
2A^Tb\\
d\end{array} \right],
$$
where $z$ is a vector of Lagrange multipliers.
This then leads to the below two conditions in order to solve the system

For $\bar{A}=
\left[\begin{array}{c} 
A\\
C\end{array} \right]$, $\bar{A}$ must have linearly independent columns.
$C$ must have linearly independent rows.

Now, if we include a bounds on $x$, such that $x\ge 0$, from my understanding, we instead have the following optimality conditions
$$
\left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
2A^TA & C^T &-I\\
C & 0 &0\end{array} \right]
\left[\begin{array}{c} 
x\\
z_1\\
z_2\end{array} \right]=
\left[\begin{array}{c} 
2A^Tb\\
d\end{array} \right],\;\;z_{2,i}x_i=0,
$$
where $z_1$ and $z_2$ are vectors of Lagrange multipliers.
In order to find a solution to this system, do the above conditions 1 and 2 on matrices $\bar{A}$ and $C$ still hold? If not, how do we find the conditions on $A$ and $C$ for an optimal solution to the problem:
$$
\min_x ||Ax-b||^2 
$$
$$
s.t.\;\;Cx=d,\;\;x\ge0
$$
Thank you.

As long the set $\left\{ \boldsymbol{y} \mid \boldsymbol{d} = \boldsymbol{C} \boldsymbol{y}, \boldsymbol{y} \geq 0 \right\}$ is not empty, the problem will have a solution.
For conditions to check such cases, you may have a look on Farkas' Lemma.
In most cases, there are physical or other explanations why the set is not empty.
